# VB.Net: Retrieving items from a ConcurrentQueue on a thread

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, concurrent-queue

I've got a class running on one thread which listens for data and pushes it into a ConcurrentQueue of strings.  I'm adding data to it using Enqueue and I can see that the queue length is growing so I know that data is being queue correctly.

Another class running on another thread should then take each piece of data out on a FIFO basis.  However, it simply does nothing.  Here's the loop that *should* pull the data out of the queue:

```
Dim data As String = Nothing

While Globals.queueMessages.Count > 0

    queueMessages.TryDequeue(data)
    If (data IsNot Nothing) Then
        Console.WriteLine(data)
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("Failed to dequeue")
    End If
End While
```

As well as checking the number of items in the queue using Count() I've also tried IsEmpty too.  Same result !?

Whilst there seems to be quite a few articles about using ConcurrentQueue in C#, I've not found any VB.Net examples so I'm a bit stuck.

Help !

UPDATE: Wrapping my While ... End While in a Do ... Loop does work but then ties up the thread when nothing is happening so it's probably not recommended.  Is there a more elegant way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you found out, you need to loop continuously as the queue is allowed to be empty and you don't want the loop to drop out. Just sleep for a small interval to allow it to be refilled. A simple boolean flag for controlling when your operation is done is all thats required for terminating.

```
    Dim data As String = Nothing

    While mCancel = False

        If queueMessages.TryDequeue(data) Then
            Console.WriteLine(data)
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("Empty")
            Thread.sleep(50)
        End If

    End While
```

Comment: Nice tip about using a boolean flag, I hadn't thought of that.  There's no sleep() property being offered for my thread.  I'm creating it with Dim threadParser As Task = Nothing and then starting the thread with threadParser = Task.Factory.StartNew(Sub() Parser.Process())  Would switching to threads be better ?

Comment: General rule is don't sleep on a threadpool thread. If its a short lived thing then go for it. If your thread will hang around for the life of the app then add a dedicated thread. Import system.threading to access thread.sleep

Comment: The threads will hang around for as long as the Windows application will - ideally this will be days or even weeks so I've converted it to threads and it's running fine.  Thank you very much !